# Cannot find Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was executing this command:

```
$obj = Get-AzDataFactory -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $adfName
```

I get this error but the ADF exists.

```
HTTP Status Code: NotFound Error Code: ResourceNotFound 
Error Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories/*******' 
under resource group 'DEV*****RG' was not found.
```

When this command runs, the ADF is listed!

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "DEV*****RG"
```

Comment: could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Get-AzDataFactory**V2**' is the correct command

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. After 48 hours, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.